# Связь полей с состоянием React и Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

У меня в приложении есть поля, которые связаны с состоянием redux.
При в воде в поле состояние обновляется. Все как во всех книгак по основам реакта.

Два (возможно глупых) вопроса:

1. В реальных проэктах инпуты всегда связаны со стейтом?
2. Правильно ли связывать их через оброботчик события onChange, чтоб каждый ввод пользователя попадал в стейт? Как в таком случае выполнять валидацию поля с задержкой?

Части кода проекта(stackoverflow просит прикладывать код, но я думаю вопрос и так ясен).

Поля ввода в компоненте формы:

```
        <label htmlFor="reg-phone">Phone</label>
        <input id="reg-phone" placeholder="+XXX XX XXX XX XX"
               value={props.phone}
               onChange={props.fieldChangeHandle}
        />
        {props.errors && props.errors.phone && <div className="error">{props.errors.phone}</div>}

        {props.positions && props.positions.length && <>
            <label className="mb-20" htmlFor="positions">Select your position</label>
            {props.positions.map((element, index) => <div key={index} className="radio-element">
                    <input id={index} type="radio" name="positions"
                           onChange={props.positionChangeHandle}
                           defaultChecked={index === props.position}/>
                    <label htmlFor={index}>{element}</label>
                </div>)
            }
        </>}
```

Контейнер формы:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    phone: state.regForm.phone,
    position: state.regForm.position,
    errors: state.regForm.errors,
    positions: state.page.positions
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    positionChange,
    fieldChange,
};

class RegFormContainer extends React.Component {
    positionChangeHandle = event => this.props.positionChange(event.target.id);
    fieldChangeHandle = event => {
        this.props.fieldChange(event.target.id.split('-')[1], event.target.value);
    };

render () {
    return <RegForm
        position={this.props.position}
        positions={this.props.positions}
        phone={this.props.phone}
        errors={this.props.errors}
        positionChangeHandle={this.positionChangeHandle}
        fieldChangeHandle = {this.fieldChangeHandle}
    />
}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(RegFormContainer);
```

Редьюсер:

```
const initialState = {
    phone: '',
    position: 0,
    errors: null
};

export default function regFormReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FIELD_CHANGE:
            return {...state, [action.payload.id]: action.payload.value};
        case POSITION_CHANGE:
            return {...state, position: action.payload};
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> В реальных проэктах инпуты всегда связаны со стейтом?

а что здесь Вас должно смущать?) это нормально. как альтернатива, Вы можете для 
валидации формы использовать `ref`, чтобы проверять состояние *инпутов*. как Вам угодно. но на **моё мнение**, использовать **store** для хранения данный форм - не очень идея. проблема в том, что при каждом изменении **store** перерисовывается (срабатывает каждый **reducer**). если он маленький - нагрузка практически незначительная. если же он огромен, то зачем? все данные формы Вы можете хранить в **state компонента**.

> Правильно ли связывать их через обработчик события onChange, чтоб
>   каждый ввод пользователя попадал в стейт? Как в таком случае выполнять
>   валидацию поля с задержкой?

любой обработчик будет правильный, если Вы добьетесь своего результата